# Cannot get TableLayout and TableRows correct. How to stretch column?

Tags: android, xml

This must very very basic, sorry for that. But I cannot get the columns like I want them to be. Or the first row, to be precise.

I want the first row to have only one column, which fills the whole width. Next rows will have more columns and they seem to behave like I want. However, looks like the first column width in the first row is following the width of the first column in the second row. That's not what I want. This is copied from one example I found in Android developer portal. I've tried all combinations that I could imagine. What I'm missing?

Don't mind the hard-coded texts, naturally they won't be in the final solution...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:stretchColumns="*"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/firstRow">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="2.07"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="96sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Copy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Save" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Copy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Save" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the **textView**

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="2.07"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="96sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called spanning, in Table terminology. In Android xml the attribute for that is `layout_span`.

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/firstRow">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="2.07"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="96sp" />
</TableRow>
```